# Add vertical scrollbar to shinyjs dropdownbutton - shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am using shinyjs dropdownbutton to display radiobuttons in the shinydashboard. 
I need your help for the following issue,

Add vertical scrollbar for the dropdown.

Please check my code,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"), 
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(width = 1),
                                  dropdownButton(
                                    tags$h3("List of Input"),
                                    radioButtons("attr_var","", c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")),
                                    circle = TRUE, status = "danger", icon = icon("gear"), width = "100px",
                                    tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to see inputs")))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in Advance,
SJB.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite a late answer, but the trick is to set the `max-height` and `overflow-y` values inside the dropdownButton. Your code could look like:

```
dropdownButton(
    circle = TRUE, status = "danger", icon = icon("gear"), width = "100px",
    tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to see inputs")))),
    div(style='max-height: 80vh; overflow-y: auto;',
    tags$h3("List of Input"),
    radioButtons("attr_var","", c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"))))
```